# Rotate all points to align with a vector

Tags: vector, rotation

I have a vector v = (x,y,z), and I want to rotate all points such that the point (x,y,z) = (0,0,sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2).  In other words, I want to make the direction of the vector v be the z axis, and rotate all points such that this is true.

I want the point (1,1,0) to go to (0,0,sqrt(2)), and the point (0,0,1) to go to (-1/(sqrt(2)),-1/sqrt(2),0) given a v of (1,1,0).

I am working in unity3d's left handed axis system, where y is vertical.

My current method is this, using with v = (vx,vy,vz) and x,y,z being the point to be rotated.

```
float vx = 1;
float vy = 1;
float vz = 0;



float c1 = -vz/(sqrt(vx*vx + vz*vz));
float c2 = -sqrt(vx*vx + vz*vz)/sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy + vz*vz);
float s1 = -vx/(sqrt(vx*vx + vz*vz));
float s2 = -vy/sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy + vz*vz);


float rx = x * c1  + y*s1*s2 - z*s1*c2;
float ry = x * 0 + y*c2 + z * s2;
float rz = x * s1 - y*s2*c1 + z*c1*c2;
```

Comment: In three dimensions, what you describe is only defined up to one degree of freedom. Is this an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, find axis of rotation by taking cross product of (0,0,1) then use this as the axis of rotation with the angle being the angle between the vector (0,0,1) and (vx,vy,vz).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a 3x3 Matrix *f* with *fv*=(0,0,1), |*x*|=|*fx*|; this needs

```
      ( t1  t2  t3 )
f =   ( u1  u2  u3 )
      ( w1  w2  w3 )
```

where *w* := *v* / |*v*|, and t, u, w are pairwise orthogonal and |*t*|=|*u*|=|*w*|=1.

Chosing *t* and *u* depends on what you want to do, but if you just need any *t* and *u*, get some via the 3d [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).